# RainTPL loop into loop

Tags: php, html, template-engine

i have to use loop into child loop. i can not use child loop in parent loop.

for example this is my sample code

```
{loop="user_list"}
  {$key} - {$value.name}</br>
  {loop="list"}
     {$key} - {$value.id}</br>
  {/loop}
{/loop}
```

Comment: Its difficult to understand what is the problem ? Can you be please more specific ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Try adding $ to your variables.

{loop="$user_list"}
    {$key} - {$value.name}</br>
    {loop="$list"}
        {$key} - {$value.id}</br>
    {/loop}
{/loop}

Below one sample that worked for me with RainTPL3:

{loop="$letters"}
    {$key} - {$value.name}</br>
    {loop="$numbers"}
        {$key} - {$value.id}</br>
    {/loop}
{/loop}


- Input:
$letters = array( "A" => array("name" => "Letter A"),
                  "B" => array("name" => "Letter B"),
                  "C" => array("name" => "Letter C"));
$numbers = array(0 => array("id" => "Number 0"),
                 1 => array("id" => "Number 1"),
                 2 => array("id" => "Number 2")); 

- Output:

A - Letter A
0 - Number 0
1 - Number 1
2 - Number 2
B - Letter B
0 - Number 0
1 - Number 1
2 - Number 2
C - Letter C
0 - Number 0
1 - Number 1
2 - Number 2
```